# How to load third party libraries in isomorphic reactjs apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, stripe-payments, mern

I am trying to use the stripe library specifically stripe elements so I can set up a custom form for payment processing. I am using the mern-starter in the server.js file I have the following code. You can see that at the bottom I have added a script tag to import stripe. However, in my client folder I have a component that is trying to make use of stripe and it cannot seem to access it. My guess is that is doesn't know it exists yet, but how can I circumvent that issue? I have looked at a react component that specifically deals with loading scripts, but it didn't seem like a great solution. I was just wondering if anyone else out there knows a better way. I know I could use a callback and have that dispatch and action(using REDUX) when it is done loading and only then allow my stripe code to execute, but again this seems pretty annoying to do. Any insights on this issue would be appreciated.

```
return `
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ${head.base.toString()}
    ${head.title.toString()}
    ${head.meta.toString()}
    ${head.link.toString()}
    ${head.script.toString()}

    ${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `<link rel='stylesheet' href='${assetsManifest['/app.css']}' />` : ''}
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://res.cloudinary.com/hashnode/image/upload/v1455629445/static_imgs/mern/mern-favicon-circle-fill.png" type="image/png" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">${html}</div>
    <script>
      window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)};
      ${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
      `//<![CDATA[
      window.webpackManifest = ${JSON.stringify(chunkManifest)};
      //]]>` : ''}
    </script>
    <script src='${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? assetsManifest['/vendor.js'] : '/vendor.js'}'></script>
    <script src='${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? assetsManifest['/app.js'] : '/app.js'}'></script>
    <script src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>
  </body>
</html>`;
```

Comment: put `<script src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>` in the head or, at the very least, before your app (`app.js` in this case).

Comment: oh wow. It has been a long day. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'll write out a proper answer and you can accept it if my solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your application scripts are running before `stripe.js` has been loaded.

put `<script src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>` in the head or, at the very least, before your app (`app.js` in this case).